# AzurePowerShell@5 not working with Az.Resources 6.16.0

Tags: azure, powershell, ado

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline using the AzurePowerShell@5 task.  I pass the service connection to the task and it logs in to Azure.  That part is good.

The PowerShell code that is executed by the task calls Get-AzADServicePrincipalAppRollAssignment, which requires the latest Az.Resources 6.16.0.  Az.Resources 6.16.0 in turn requires Az.Accounts 2.16.0.  However, the AzurePowerShell@5 task installed Az.Accounts 2.15.1.

When I try to remove Az.Accounts 2.15.1 and install the latest version, I get the following error.  Not sure how to get around that.  Is there a lock on the assembly because it was used to log in to Azure?

I have read about using a PowerShell session to load modules but my hunch is that would log me out of Azure?

Comment: The `AzurePowershell@5` task would use the modules installed on the agent, if you are using a Microsoft-hosted agent, I found [here](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/9445) that they are going to update the `Az` module to v11.3.1. However looking [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az/11.3.1/Content/Az.psm1) we can see that this Az version will be loading a minimum version of 2.15.1, but I assume that 2.16.0 will be loaded if the Az-module is installed when the 2.16.0 version of `Az.Accounts` already exists in PSGallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Galna Greta, The **`AzurePowershell@5`** task will only use the Az version installed on the agent.

I tried Installing **`Az.Accounts - 2.16.0`**
and **`Az.Resources`** in Azure Powershell task with Install-Module command but it failed. Thus instead of using **`AzurePowershell@5`** task I used ***Powershell@2*** task like below: -

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Check if Az.Accounts module is installed, if not, install it
      if (-not (Get-Module -Name Az.Accounts -ListAvailable)) {
          Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts -Force -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -RequiredVersion 2.16.0
      } else {
          Update-Module -Name Az.Accounts -Force -AllowClobber -RequiredVersion 2.16.0
      }
      
      
      if (-not (Get-Module -Name Az.Resources -ListAvailable)) {
          Install-Module -Name Az.Resources -Force -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -RequiredVersion 6.16.0
      } else {
          
          $azAccountsVersion = (Get-InstalledModule -Name Az.Accounts).Version
          
          Install-Module -Name Az.Resources -Force -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -RequiredVersion $azAccountsVersion -AllowPrerelease
      }
      
      
      Get-InstalledModule -Name Az.Accounts, Az.Resources | Select-Object Name, Version
      
      $SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "q-xxxxxxxx_rsVKJKbRs" -AsPlainText -Force
      $TenantId = '83xxxxxx8592395'
      $ApplicationId = 'cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxb'
      $Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ApplicationId, $SecurePassword
      Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $Credential
      Get-AzADServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId c0xxxxxxxxxx35cb
```

**Output: -**

[image]

Comment: I faced the same as @SiddheshDesai.  I looked in to approaching it the same as you suggested.  I got stuck with the logging in to Azure bit.  For reasons, I would prefer to use the Service Connection as configured in Azure DevOps.  I did not really get very far with trying to make that work with Connect-AzAccount though.

Unfortunately, my solution was to stop using the XXX-AzADServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment cmdlets and instead hitting Microsoft Graph directly.  I feel like I was defeated by Microsoft on this one.